# Android Kotlin cannot use list.sort() with lambda

Tags: android, sorting, lambda, kotlin

having a string list, for filter it takes the lambda expression directly

```
val list= ArrayList<String>()
list.add("eee")
list.add("888")
list.add("ccc")

list.filter({it.length > 0})

// this passing function works too
list.filter(fun(it) = it.length > 0)
```

it is defined as taking lambda function type: `(T) -> Boolean`

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    return filterTo(ArrayList<T>(), predicate)
}
```

but similar syntax does not work with `sort()`. It asks to use sortWith instead. Don’t understand why cant directly pass the lambda expression as in the `filter()` call.

Could someone explain why `sort()` cannot use the similar syntax for a lambda function directly?

```
list.sort({ first: String, second: String ->
    first.compareTo(second)
})
```

list.sort is defined as below, also taking a lambda function: `(T, T) -> Int`:

```
public inline fun <T> MutableList<T>.sort(comparison: (T, T) -> Int): Unit = throw NotImplementedError()
```

but it gives error “*using sort((T, T) -> Int) : Unit is an error Use sortWith(Comparator(comparison)) instead*"

both `sort()` and `sortWith()` have same return type of `Unit` in the define

for `sortWith()` it has to passing the Comparator, like:

```
list.sortWith(Comparator { first, second ->
    first.compareTo(second)
})
```

which is defined as:

```
@kotlin.jvm.JvmVersion
public fun <T> MutableList<T>.sortWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): Unit {
    if (size > 1) java.util.Collections.sort(this, comparator)
}
```

Also the Arrays.sort can use the same syntax as `filter()` and it takes the lambda function directly

```
var listStr = TextUtils.join(", ", list);
Arrays.sort(arrayOf(listStr)) { first: String, second: String ->
    first.compareTo(second)
}
```

the Arrays.sort is defined as:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `sort` is deprecated and marked as `DeprecationLevel.ERROR`.

```
@Deprecated("Use sortWith(Comparator(comparison)) instead.", ReplaceWith("this.sortWith(Comparator(comparison))"), level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
@JvmVersion
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
public inline fun <T> MutableList<T>.sort(comparison: (T, T) -> Int): Unit = throw NotImplementedError()
```

That's why you are getting an error and the compiler asks to use `sortWith` instead.

Comment: thanks @Bob! I guess the question is more of on why kotlin puts this 'deprecated' sort there and not allow you to use. it would be better for the function on the collection type to have similar calling syntax.